# Replicating Flight Mechanics of Star Wars Battlefront (2015)

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to replicate the flight mechanics from Star Wars Battlefront (2015) in Unity and I can't get my head around what exactly is going on.

Specifically, how do I get the camera to behave like this using Unity and C#:

https://youtu.be/gxZdOUiEiyY?t=1m1s

I don't mind if you don't give code, I'm just struggling to understand what happens and when in terms of camera movements and rotation.

Comment: Remember that with a camera like that the player won't be able to hit anything without auto-aim. The line-of-sight and line-of-fire are far too different in that perspective.

Answer (score 5):

1. Decide the *desired* camera location. In this case a distance `x` behind the fighter plus an offset `y` in the up direction relative to the fighter. `x` and `y` can depend on the current velocity, but for starters use constant numbers.
2. Decide the desired camera "up" rotation. I guess it's just the rotation of the fighter.
3. Write a simple function that takes the current camera location and the *desired* camera location, then move the camera from the current location towards the desired one. Make the speed of that move dependent on the distance between current and desired location.
4. Same as 3 for rotation.
5. Take the flight direction of the fighter, add a certain distance to get a point in front of the fighter. Make the camera look at that point. Or use the inverse, make the fighter fly where the camera looks.

Answer (score 3):

The camera tries to follow the fighter, but not in the same speed the fighter moves, a bit slower, with a specific cap. With cap I mean, that the camera seems to have a specific limit for the "deviation angle".
"Deviation angle" means the angle between the direction vector of the camera and the direction vector of the fighter.
Imagine the camera is bound to the fighter by a kind of "leash". You can see this at 1:40-2:00 or 2:17-2:29.

To reproduce this I would adjust the orientation of the camera with a delay (slower velocity), maybe interpolated by a simple function (via e.g. animation curves). But with specific bounds, so that the fighter is not able to move out of the camera view. To achieve this you should determine a maximum "deviation angle". The closer the "deviation angle" comes to maximum, the faster the camera is adjusted up to the maximum speed the figther can move or maybe even faster. You could use an animation curve again, to make it look smoother.

Comment: It looks to me like the opposite: The player's input drives the camera direction directly, and the fighter is being steered to chase the reticle projected through the center of the camera frame. This helps the player line up shots since they control the reticle directly, making the controls feel intuitive and responsive. Applying delay or catch-up behaviour to the camera orientation is likely to make the controls feel squishy or sluggish for shooter gameplay.